# Snookered myself with class inheritance, need some guidance

Tags: c++

I have a Player class... He needs access to components inside PlayerStateFlying and PlayerStateHit classes so I inherited from them...

```
class PlayerStateFlying
{
    // Includes a function that sets Player::currentState = something
}

class PlayerStateHit
{
    // Includes a function that sets Player::currentState = something
}

class Player : public PlayerStateFlying,
               public PlayerStateHit
{
    public:
        STATE currentState; // Needs to be accessed by the State classes
}
```

Problem is, my State classes need access to one of Player's properties

How do I go about solving this problem?

**---------EDIT-----------**

So should it be something like this? P.S I can't quite get it to work

```
class IBaseStates
{
    public:
        STATE currentState;
}

class PlayerStateFlying : public IBaseStates
{
    // Includes a function that sets IBaseStates::currentState = something
}

class PlayerStateHit : public IBaseStates
{
    // Includes a function that sets IBaseStates::currentState = something
}

class Player : public IBaseStates
{
    // Includes a function that checks what IBaseStates::currentState equals
}
```

Here is an example of my dilemma:

```
void Player::ChangeState( STATE state )
{
    switch( state )
    {
    case FLYING:
        currentState = FLYING;
        break;
    case HIT:
        currentState = HIT;
        break;
    }
}

void Player::StateUpdate()
{
    switch( currentState )
    {
    case FLYING:
        PlayerStateFlying::Update( );
        currentTextureIndex = PlayerStateFlying::current;
        break;
    case HIT:
        PlayerStateHit::Update( );
        currentTextureIndex = PlayerStateHit::current;
        break;
    }
}

void PlayerStateHit::Update( )
{
    ...
            currentState = FLYING;
            index = 0;
    ...    
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Google "state design pattern" for some ideas.

Comment: Why don't you just add `STATE currentState;` to the state classes as well?

Comment: I think inheriting from multiple base classes is a very bad idea in general. The names of your "base" classes (`PlayerState...`) also don't suggest that inheritance is the proper solution here (you are saying that a `Player` _is_ a (special instance of) a `PlayerStateFlying`? What does a `PlayerStateFlying` look like anyway?).

Comment: You're absolutely right, if anything.. the PlayerState_'s should inherit from Player, they re-define the textures and movement functionality of the Player.. that makes much more sense.

Comment: Why does `Player` inherit from `IBaseStates`?

Comment: He needs to know what currentState is aswell as the States actually setting what currentState is

Comment: A state shouldn't set what its itself is, a state machine should do the job. In your case the player is the state machine.

Comment: But my HitState needs to tell my Player that he is all finished with being hit and that the Player can go back to FlyingState

Comment: NEGATIVE VOTE??? F OFF, i'm trying to figure something out... bar stewards! Whoever negative voted me, Just because you are too dumb or too lazy to understand the question, does not mean it's worded incorrectly!

Comment: @JamesT: It means that someone finds the question not useful or not well-researched.  Raging about it isn't going to change their opinion, and may well attract more negativity.  Just chill.  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A player should be the one setting what the current state is. Not the state itself. And the state update function should look something like:

```
void Player::StateUpdate() {
    mCurrentState->update(this);
}

void PlayerHitState(Player * player) {
    player->setCurrentState(player->getStateFromListOfAvailableStates(FLYING))
}
```

A simple state machine should store all the needed states and transitions. Like you can't fly if you are in water or something similar.

Comment: ahhhhh the state has a reference to the player... you beauty, I think that's what I needed to see. thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget about polymorphism. You don't need to implement any `switch`'es.

I think the solution should look like:

```
class PlayerState {
}

class PlayerStateFlying : public PlayerState {
}

class PlayerStateHit : public PlayerState {
}
```

Now your `Player` class (object) should contain (or access) a state object:

```
class Player {
protected:
    PlayerState *playerState;
public:
    void setPlayerState(PlayerState *newState);
}
```

`setPlayerState()` should look like:

```
Player::setPlayerState(PlayerState *newState) {
    playerState = newState;
}
```

Now you can simply rewrite your methods for the future supporting variety of PlayerState subclasses:

```
void Player::StateUpdate() {
    playerState->Update(); // Polymorphism!
    currentTextureIndex = playerState->current;
}
```

In the next method you can still use a switch if you still really need to store your `currentState` variable and use it:

```
void Player::ChangeState( STATE state ) {
    switch( state ) {
    case FLYING:
        currentState = FLYING;
        playerState = new PlayerStateFlying();
        break;
    case HIT:
        currentState = HIT;
        playerState = new PlayerStateHit();
        break;
    }
}
```

... but there is another -- more convenient solution -- `setPlayerState` -- we already have it, but if we still need `currentState` enum (or int or whatever) variable, we can simply expand our `PlayerState` class (and subclasses) with a new field -- `label`:

```
class PlayerState {
public:
    int label;
}

PlayerStateFlying::PlayerStateFlying() {
    label = FLYING;
}

PlayerStateHit::PlayerStateHit() {
    label = HIT;
}
```

Now it is possible to:

```
Player::setPlayerState(PlayerState *newState) {
    playerState = newState;
    currentState = playerState->label;
}
```

You can also try with constant fields, that is:

```
class PlayerState {
public:
    const int label;
}

PlayerStateFlying::PlayerStateFlying() : label(FLYING) {};

PlayerStateHit::PlayerStateHit() : label(HIT) {};
```

Regards.

Comment: Oh mama!!! That was uber comprehensive... I love it too!! booyaka shannnn! Gonna implement that interface right now! yip yip!

Comment: Glad you like it. I suppose it still needs some modifications to fit in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a common class that stores the State and the information that is needed access to and inherit from it in both Player states.

Comment: I think I get you, let me re-jiggle the code and see if I can get it to work.